# Como tirar a Barra de título e ajustar o tamanho da tela no tkinter do Python?

Tags: tkinter

Olá!
Gostaria de saber como colocar a tela em um tamanho menor no tkinter Python.
O programa abaixo deixa em tela cheia. Até agora não consigo alterar o tamanho.

```
from tkinter import *
janela = Tk()

janela.title(" >>> Janela menor sem a Barra de Título <<< ")

janela.wm_attributes('-fullscreen','true')   # retira a barra de título

janela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!

## Código com uma tela dimensionável sem a barra de título

from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()

janela.title(" >>> Janela dimensionável sem a Barra de Título <<< ")

janela.overrideredirect(True)

janela.geometry('340x300+500+200')

janela.mainloop()

O link mostra onde encontrei a resposta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966119/display-fullscreen-mode-on-tkinter

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou usar o método `geometry` para redimensionar a sua tela. Algo como `janela.geometry('500x500')`.

Você pode ver algumas variações disso [aqui](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-geometry-method-in-tkinter/).

Comment: Olá! Até ontem não tinha encontrado a resposta mas mas depois da sua dica resolvi dar mais uma procurada na internet e aqui mesmo no site encontrei a resposta usando o overrideredirect(True) no lugar do wm_attributes('-fullscreen','true'). Vou colocar o código mais abaixo. Obrigado.